# GTK::TreeModelSort not longer accepting GTK ListStore in Ruby/ GTK3

Tags: ruby, treeview

At the moment, i am upgrading a ruby / GTK3 program under Linux to the newest libs/gems.

I took this project over from a person that not only compiled all from source, but also used old libraries. Therefore it's hard for me to reinstall the software myself, which is a big risk.

Since upgrading, i noticed the handling of dependencies is different, i really need to include the file itself where it is used, instead of including all files in the main file.

Also, a lot of GTK statements are deprecated, like GTK::Dialog::Flags should be replaced by GTK::DialogFlags.

But what really bugs me is that a Gtk::TreeView no longer accepts a ListStore. It tells me: wrong argument type GTK::ListStore (expected hash)

The code i use is:

```
model = Gtk::ListStore.new(Product, String, String, Integer, String)
modelSort = Gtk::TreeModelSort.new(model)
treeView = Gtk::TreeView.new(modelSort)
...
```

I checked the API @ http://ruby-gnome2.osdn.jp/hiki.cgi?Gtk%3A%3ATreeModelSort and http://ruby-gnome2.osdn.jp/hiki.cgi?Gtk%3A%3ATreeModel, but states it accepts a TreeModel, where the Liststore is a generic version of.

Anybody has a clue what could be wrong here?

Thanks in advance,

Martin